# Comparing double values for format in java?

Tags: java, double

I need to comparing some double values for format

For example :

```
double a = 18.0;
double b = 18.00;
double c = 19.0;

a == b //Comparing for format => False
a == c //Comparing for format => True
```

Is there any method or idea?

Answer (score 3):

There is literally no difference between `a` and `b`.  `double` values don't know their format; they're *just numbers.*

If you stored them as strings, that would be different, but `a` and `b` are exactly the same values.

Comment: i know "double values don't know their format; they're just numbers", but when convert double to string, How do I compare strings for differences in format?

Comment: @hossein what `String`s are you looking at?  Your example code doesn't have any `String`s.  As it stands, there is no way whatsoever to distinguish between `a` and `b`.  You can convert a `double` into a `String` with different formats; you could conceivably inspect `String`s to figure out what format they have.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use Decimal:

```
java.math.BigDecimal.equals(BigDecimal val)
```

So

```
BigDecimal bg1, bg2;

    bg1 = new BigDecimal("20.0");
    bg2 = new BigDecimal("20.00");
```

with equals bg1 and bg2 Are not equal in value and scale

Answer (score 0):

"==" simply you wont be able to do that, use OOP, create some class and pass these two values, convert both to string, than compare, return value accordingly